# Python API for Github, getting contents in specific directory for specific branch not returning all content

Tags: python, git, github

Using the [PyGithub API](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html), I am attempting to retrieve all contents from a specific folder from a specific branch of a repository hosted with Github. I can't share the actual repository or specifics regarding the data, but the code I am using is this:

```py
import github
import json
import requests
import base64

from collections import namedtuple
Package = namedtuple('Package', 'name version')

# Parameters
gh_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
header = {"Authorization": f"token {gh_token}"}
gh_hostname = 'devtopia.xxx.com'
gh = github.Github(base_url=f'https://{gh_hostname}/api/v3', login_or_token = gh_token)
repo_name = "xxxxxxxxx/SupportFiles"
conda_meta = "xxxxxxx/bin/Python/envs/xxxxxx-xx/conda-meta"
repo = gh.get_repo(repo_name)


def parse_conda_meta(branch):
    package_list = []
    meta_contents = repo.get_contents(conda_meta, ref=branch)  #<< Returns less files than expected for 
                                                               # a specified branch "xxx/release/3.2.0",
                                                               # returns expected number of files for 
                                                               # "master" branch.
    for i, pkg in enumerate(meta_contents):
        if ".json" in pkg.name:  # filter for JSON files
            print(i, pkg.name)
            # Need to use GitHub Data API (REST) blobs instead of easier
            # `github` with `pkg.decoded_content` here because that method
            # only works with files <= 1MB whereas Data API allows for
            # reading files <= 100MB.
            resp = requests.get(f"https://devtopia.xxxx.com/api/v3/repos/xxxxxxxxx/SupportFiles/git/blobs/{pkg.sha}?ref={branch}", headers=header)
            pkg_cont = json.loads(base64.b64decode(json.loads(resp.content)["content"]))
            package_list.append(Package(pkg_cont['name'], pkg_cont['version']))
        else:
            print('>>', i, pkg.name)
    return package_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pkgs = parse_conda_meta("xxx/release/3.2.0")
    print(pkgs)
    print(len(pkgs))
```

For some reason that I can't get to the bottom of, I am not getting the correct number of files returned by `repo.get_contents(conda_meta, ref=branch)`. For the branch that I am specifying, when that branch is checked out I am seeing 186 files in the conda-meta folder. However, `repo.get_contents(conda_meta, ref=branch)` returns only 182, I am missing four JSON files.

Is there some limitation to `repo.get_contents` that I'm not aware of? I've been reading the doc but can't find anything that hints at the problem I am having. There is one bit about it only handling files up to 1mb, but I am seeing files larger than this returned (e.x: python is 1.204mb and is returned in the list of files). I believe this just applies to reading file content over 1mb, which I deal with by using the GitHub Data API (REST) further downstream. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for reading, any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: I see you anonymized the hostname, is this for GitHub Enterprise? If so, which version?

Comment: Hey, I suppose that's okay to share, we use [Devtopia](http://www.devtopia.com/), see updated original post with hostname not anonymized. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update with solution!**

**The Problem:**

After some more digging, I have found the problem's cause. It's not to do with the code above or `repo.get_contents(conda_meta, ref=branch)` specifically. It is actually a unix/windows clash that was mistakenly introduced into our repository for this specific branch "xxx/release/3.2.0" but not present in others.

So what was the problem? NTFS (and Windows more broadly) by default is case insensitive, but Git is from a Unix world and is case-sensitive by default

We inadvertently created two folders for Python in the bin directory of the `conda_meta` path (`xxxxxx/bin/`), one folder called "Python" and one called "python" (note the lower-case). When pulling the repository locally, only the "Python" folder shows up containing all 168 files. On GitHub, however, the path with "Python" contains 182 files while the path with "python" contains the remaining 4 files.

**The Solution:**

Solution is to add a `conda_meta_folders` parameter that takes a list of paths to `parse_conda_meta` and search each directory. There might be a slicker solution though, I'm looking into whether it is possible to do something like `git config core.ignorecase true` with the PyGithub API. Does anyone know if it is possible to have PyGithub honor this or be configured for this?

Comment: `core.ignorecase` is not a setting to *control* Git, but rather a setting to *inform* Git. It tells Git: *Hey, if you create Python/, and then write python/foo.py, it'll wind up in Python/foo.py instead*. If you turn it on or off, you're mis-informing Git: it's set up based on how your *computer actually behaves* (Git tries a few things out when you first create the repo, to figure out how your computer behaves).